# pytz timezone DST issue

Tags: python, pytz

I'm passing two naive dates to a form.  Then using pytz to ensure the timezones are set as EST.  However, it results in an error.  I'm guessing this is due to the DST issue.  Dates and DST are confusing.  Can someone enlighten me as to how to make the "DST proof"?

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from datetime import datetime
import pytz


class SearchForm(serializers.Serializer):
    start_date = serializers.DateField(required=True)
    end_date = serializers.DateField(required=False)

    def save(self):
        # Doesn't actually save, 
        start_date = self.validated_data['start_date']
        end_date = self.validated_data['end_date']

        # Convert dates to EST timezone
        est = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
        start_date = datetime.combine(start_date, time.min).astimezone(est)
        end_date = datetime.combine(end_date, time.max).astimezone(est)

        print(f'Start date: {start_date} => {start_date.tzinfo}')
        print(f'End date: {end_date} => {end_date.tzinfo}')

        assert start_date.tzinfo == end_date.tzinfo

        # Filter based on timeframe
        qs = self.filter_timeframe(qs, start_date, end_date)

        return SearchSerializer(qs, many=True)
```

Passing a the `start_date` as "2018-11-1" and `end_date` as "2018-11-5" results in an `AssertionError`. Printing out the dates results in:

```
Start date: 2018-11-01 00:00:00-04:00 => America/New_York
End date: 2018-11-05 23:59:59.999999-05:00 => America/New_York
```

The question is why is the `end_date` timezone `-05:00` and not `-04:00` like `start_date`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

America/New_York is not the same as EST. The former adjusts for the daylight saving shifts. The latter is fixed to be Eastern Standard Time.
Use:

```
est = pytz.timezone('EST')
```

Comment: Consider me enlightened.  Figured that was the same as EST, but I was obviously wrong.  Problem solved.